# last.group statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set sorted by x1 and x2. For every value of x1 I want to only print the last value of x2. How do I do this? Would it be something like:

`if last.x2 then print;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Itzy was close, but the LAST statement needs to be changed to refer to X1, like in the following:

```
data tmp;
 set mydataset;
 by x1 x2;
 if last.x1;
run;

proc print data=tmp; run;
```

Answer (score 5):

You're right that you can use the `last` statement, but you can't use it in a print statement. Try this:

```
data tmp;
 set mydataset;
 by x1 x2;
 if last.x1;
run;

proc print data=tmp; run;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It still prints out all of the values of x1 and x2 instead of just the value of x1 with the maximum x2.

Answer (score 0):

This will print a single row that has the largest value of x2.

```
proc sort data=mydataset;
  by x2;
run;

data tmp;
  set mydataset end=eof;
  if eof then do;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc print data=tmp;
run;
```

Note, that if there are multiple rows with the largest value, only one of them will be printed.